# Bubble sort is not sorting

Tags: java, sorting

I've written a code to input the name, day and time of a few shows, with the option to have it sorted (bubble sort) by day and name. I'm using 1.4.2 (because I have to) and an ArrayList along with a simple class.

I've been staring at this for hours, left and came back to it a bunch of times, but unfortunately, it isn't working! Any idea why?! Here's my code:

```
//method to sort and display info
public static void sortDay(){          
    for(int i = 0; i < show.size() - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < show.size() - 1; j++){
            showInfo current = (showInfo)show.get(j);
            showInfo next = (showInfo)show.get(j+1);

            if (current.day.compareTo(next.day) < 0) {
                showInfo temp = new showInfo();
                temp.name = ((showInfo)show.get(j)).name;
                temp.day = ((showInfo)show.get(j)).day;
                temp.time = ((showInfo)show.get(j)).time;

                ((showInfo)show.get(j)).time = ((showInfo)show.get(i)).time;
                ((showInfo)show.get(j)).day = ((showInfo)show.get(i)).day;
                ((showInfo)show.get(j)).name = ((showInfo)show.get(i)).name;

                ((showInfo)show.get(i)).time = temp.time;
                ((showInfo)show.get(i)).day = temp.day;
                ((showInfo)show.get(i)).name = temp.name;
            }
        } 
    }
    System.out.println("Show Information");
    for (int i = 0; i < show.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("Name: " + ((showInfo)show.get(i)).name);
        System.out.println("Day: " + ((showInfo)show.get(i)).day);
        System.out.println("Time: " + ((showInfo)show.get(i)).time);
    }       
}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't it be kind of better to just switch the objects as opposed to reassigning each field?

Comment: @JoshM How so? Sorry, I'm a bit of a noob...

Comment: Why all those typecasts? What is "show" that you need to typecast it every time? (I mean, yeah, it's obviously a list, but a list of what?)

Comment: you compare and swap different objects, compare j with j + 1 and swap i and j.

Comment: @pavel.lazar That's how my teacher's example looked! I followed it and now I'm not sure. So I read a bit about it, but it was all basically the same. How do I fix it? :(

Comment: @Sal Well, you could use `ArrayList#set(int, Object)` to actually swap the objects.

Comment: I need to swap them myself. That's the point of the assignment. Bubble swap!

Comment: @Sal Unless you plan on modifying the memory addresses yourself, I think you kind of need to use `ArrayList#set(int, Object)`. Besides, just pretend it's an array and `ArrayList#set(int, Object)` is the equivalent to `array[int] = Object`

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll assume you're using some kind of `List` - likely an `ArrayList`.

That said, the main operations for Bubble Sort are described as follows:

- Compare for ordering
- Create temporary variable
- Place left value into temporary variable
- Place right value into left value
- Place old left value into right value from temporary value

You're shuffling about the fields, which *will* lead to confusion and bugs.  Use the above approach instead.

Here it is illustrated with generics (so you don't have to cast anymore), and a capital class name, as is the convention.  I don't have a temporary variable in this example, as I already have a reference to `current`.

```
List<ShowInfo> show = new ArrayList<>(); // assume populated

public static void sortDay(){
    for(int i = 0; i < show.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < show.size() && j != i; j++) {
            ShowInfo current = show.get(i);
            ShowInfo next = show.get(j);

            // If the current day is greater than the next day, we need to swap.
            // Adjust to suit your business logic (if current is less than next).
            if (current.day.compareTo(next.day) > 0) {
                show.set(i, next);
                show.set(j, current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a generic way of doing this, perhaps you could try something like:

```
public static <T extends Comparable> void sort(final List<T> list){
    boolean remaining;
    do{
        remaining = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++){
            final T current = list.get(i);
            final T next = list.get(i+1);
            if(current.compareTo(next) < 0){
                list.set(i, next);
                list.set(i+1, current);
                remaining = true;
            }
        }
    }while(remaining);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## How do you fix it?

I'm just answering your question: how to fix the code you posted. For "*how to improve it?*" all other answers are way better than whatever I can come up with.

There are two points:

- swap on the same index, in the inner `for` (index `j`)
- correct swapping: where you have `j` write `j+1` and where you have `i` write `j`
- the other `for` is just so it will iterate enough times to get it sorted in the worst case (suggestions in other answers go for a `while`, much better)

That being said, the swapping pseudocode is:

```
if (show[j] < show[j+1]) {
    temp = j+1
    j+1 = j
    j = temp
}
```

And here is the swapping code with the fixes:

```
        if (current.day.compareTo(next.day) < 0) {
            showInfo temp = new showInfo();
            temp.name = ((showInfo)show.get(j+1)).name;
            temp.day = ((showInfo)show.get(j+1)).day;
            temp.time = ((showInfo)show.get(j+1)).time;

            ((showInfo)show.get(j+1)).time = ((showInfo)show.get(j)).time;
            ((showInfo)show.get(j+1)).day = ((showInfo)show.get(j)).day;
            ((showInfo)show.get(j+1)).name = ((showInfo)show.get(j)).name;

            ((showInfo)show.get(j)).time = temp.time;
            ((showInfo)show.get(j)).day = temp.day;
            ((showInfo)show.get(j)).name = temp.name;
        }
```

And here is the printed result (assuming `day - time - name` for each show, so we are sorting on the first int):

```
Show Information before sort
610 - -72 - 1402
838 - -184 - 1096
-478 - 248 - 934
709 - 832 - -590
2007 - 954 - -315
Show Information after sort
2007 - 954 - -315
838 - -184 - 1096
709 - 832 - -590
610 - -72 - 1402
-478 - 248 - 934
```

Answer (score -3):

```
public class myBubbleSort
{
    private static int[] a;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        getArray(10);
        System.out.println("Array before sorting");
        printArray();
        ascendingBubble();
        System.out.println("Array after ascending sort");
        printArray();
        descendingBubble();
        System.out.println("Array after descending sort");
        printArray();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Random sort");
        getArray(10);
        bubbleSort(true);
        System.out.println("Array after Random sort");
        printArray();
    }

    // print the number in random array
    public static void printArray()
    {
        for (int i : a)
        {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // generate a random array to be sorted in ascending and descending order
    public static void getArray(int size)
    {
        a = new int[size];
        int item = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            item = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            a[i] = item;
        }
    }

    // sort getArray in ascending order and bubblesort it
    public static void ascendingBubble()
    {
        int temp;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Ascending sort");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (a[j] > a[j + 1])
                {
                    temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                    a[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        bubbleSort(true);
    }

    // sort getArray in descending order and bubblesort it
    public static void descendingBubble()
    {
        int temp;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Descending sort");

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (a[j] < a[j + 1])
                {
                    temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                    a[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        bubbleSort(true);
    }

    // bubble sort algorithm
    public static void bubbleSort(boolean printTime)
    {
        boolean sorted = false;
        int pass = 1;
        int temp;
        long startTime;
        long endTime;
        long duration;

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        while (pass < a.length - 1 && (!sorted))
        {
            sorted = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
                {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[i + 1];
                    a[i + 1] = temp;
                    sorted = false;
                }
            }
            pass = pass + 1;
        }
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        duration = (endTime - startTime);
        if(printTime)
        {
            System.out.println(duration + " "+ " nano seconds");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What did you change? Where was the problem? Please try to format your code.